# When does ScrollViewer.ChangeView fail?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

`ScrollViewer.ChangeView` doesn't always work. When it doesn't - it returns `false` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252762)).

What are the conditions for that happening?

**EDIT**

Most methods either work or throw an exception. This one has a return value. This means there are conditions where it fails (and returns `false`). What are those conditions?

**EDIT 2 (after awarding the bounty)**

I awarded the bounty so as not to waste the reputation points. I'm still looking for **THE** answer. (Also, the answer was written before my edit to the question.)

Comment: Did you mean the view is already changed, but it return false? Or you think one scenario view should  be changed but it doesn't? Could you please provide a simple demo to reproduce and detail 'doesn't always work'?

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT The documentation I have linked to states that it returns `false` if the view hasn't changed. In theory this could mean - when it was already in the final state to begin with (as someone posted as an answer). But this isn't true, as I have seen - I changed the zoom/location and got a `false`. So this is a simple question about the documentation/method - when are those cases that return false? My specific case is irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't realize if there is anything confused about the description of the document. According to your description, you thought the view is changed, but the method return false. What  `I changed the zoom/location` mean? Did you change the view through `ScrollerView.ChangeView`? If sample is unnecessary, screenshots may be needed to help me understand you.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `ScrollViewer.ChangeView` signals **whether the view changes (`true`) or not (`false`)**.

The most obvious reason why the view may not change after a `ChangeView` call is because it was already displaying the requested horizontal and/or vertical offsets and/or zoom factor before the call.

Comment: `The return value ... signals whether the view changes or not` - of course. `The most obvious reason ... is because it was already displaying the requested ... before the call` - Yes, but why return a `bool` for that when other methods for changing the UI don't return anything? Presumably because there are other not `obvious` reasons. And that's my question - what are they?